# Is equating a variable to a function that takes the same variable bad programming?

Tags: c#, php, javascript

Is it improper programming to set a variable equal to the result of a function that accepts the same variable? The languages in question here are c#, javascript and PHP (not sure if this works in C families, personally).

```
var a = 1;
a = alterData(a);
```

Comment: Can't think of a case where this doesn't just make things more confusing to the reader. Is there a functional need for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Improper" how?

It is not illegal - that is, it's not a syntax violation in any language with mutable variables that I'm aware of.

It is not broken - that is, the post-condition of the expression will be the result of the function, and barring some weird concurrency effects be nice and consistent.

It's not ugly or non-idiomatic. In pretty much all languages I'm familiar with (that have mutable variables), this sort of thing is considered readable and a fine thing to do as long as `a` still *means the same thing*. Reusing `a` for some other semantic concept (like it is velocity for the first half of the function and acceleration for the second half) is not good.

If anything, programmers are moving more towards this form of programming and away from `alterData(a)` that uses side effects to change `a` under the covers.

So go right ahead.

Comment: How could `alterData(a)` change `a` under the covers? It's an `int`, it is passed by value.

Comment: Great point about it not completely altering the type of the variable (which is all too easy with scripting languages). I don't think it makes sense to extend a primitive just to do some random operation you may only need once.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ In both C#, PHP and Javascript (using `var` in c#)

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ - I was answering for the general case of the pattern - `int` and its kin of course cannot be mutated by the function.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ In both PHP and C# the parameter could be passed by reference if that is how alterData defines it.

Comment: They don't mean the same thing. One is "a before alteration", and the other is "a after alteration".

Answer (score 4):

First, you should try to use meaningful variable names.  In this case, you might have original_a and altered_a (where a should be something relevant, of course).

Second, the cost of a local variable is minimal  in most programming languages (and sometimes zero), so feel free to use them.

Third, using the functional style of immutable variables (assigned once) has merit. Apple's Swift, for example, is a modern language that is encouraging single variable assignment.  Some might argue programs are easier to read/maintain when local variables are not modified; you can see the value of the old and new in the debugger, and if something is amiss, it is easier to see where.

So, I say no, it is better to introduce another variable.

Comment: +1: Variables should be assigned once unless they are accumulators of some sort.